# Binary Search to find greatest element less than or equal to another element

Tags: c++, binary-search

I am striving for a binary search function that given a element in a vector, searches for the element that is closest to that element but still less than or equal to it. However my code is resulting in garbage numbers. Here is my code:

```
int close(vector<int> r, vector<int> g, int pos){
    int lastpos = 0;
    int mid = int((r.size())/2);
    while(mid>=1){
        if(r[lastpos+mid]>g[pos]){}
        else{
            lastpos += mid;
            if(r[lastpos+1]>g[pos] || r[lastpos]==r[r.size()-1]){
                return r[lastpos];
            }
        }
        mid/=2;
    }
    return r[0];
}
```

---

For example, if I call the function with (r, g, 1) and it is given that g[1]=3 and vector r contains {1, 3, 4}, this function will set mid to 3/2 but round it down to an integer, so one. The last position(lastpos) is defaultly set to 0. Now, my function will check if r[lastpos + mid] > g[pos] or if 3 > 3. It is not because they are equal. Now my function will continue to the else condition, and add mid to lastpos. Now lastpos = 1. Now, it'll check if r[lastpos+1]>g[pos] to see if this is the minimal value that is closest and less than or equal to g[1]. Since the next element is 4 and 4 is greater than 3 it'll return 3.

However if lastpos is the end element, then it'll simply return the end element, because there are no more numbers to check.

**Exceptions**: If there is no such element in vector r that is less than or equal to an element in vector g it'll return the first element in vector r.

**Note**: These vectors are sorted

Comment: Help me out: why not just call this with a sorted vector and a search value as parameters? Why the second vector and the index in the second vector?

Comment: Umm..... Oops.... No reason, but either way I don't think that matters

Comment: I don't think that's what's causing your problem, but if you change your function to just take the two parameters you'll save yourself copying `g`, and you'll make the intention of the function clearer.

Comment: The search algorithm is flawed. The textbook binary search tracks the starting index, the ending index, and after checking the value at the midpoint resetting the starting or the ending index, appropriately. The shown code attempts to use one index value, called `lastpos`, and then a length value called `mid` that gets halfed every time. This is error prone due to rounding errors. It's theoretically possible to code an algorithm in this manner, but it's error prone and full of edge cases. The simplest thing is to scrap this approach and do it the traditional way a binary search gets done.

Comment: Ok. Will do. Thanks

Comment: Maybe see how `lower_bound` is done.